# Does anyone recognize this grinding noise on a power window?

Tags: ford, power-windows

So, whenever I raise and lower the power window on my right side, I get this strange noise, [recorded here](https://clyp.it/tbuzl5xv).

The window operates fine.  I suppose you could guess what it is based on the frequency, however, I'm not sure I know enough about power windows.

Thanks for any help!  (It's a 1993 Ford Fiesta).  I already have the door panel off.

Answer (score 1):

Based on recorded clip i'm surpised the window still moves, if anything it sounds like the electric motor is skipping teeth on the window mechanism. There's not much to say about it from a distance on an internet message board, other than to check the window mechanism for smooth operation and possible worn out parts.

Comment: How would I recognize worn out parts?  The window basically still moves normally.  It's just really loud.  The mechanism itself is cast iron, so if this is true I'm assuming the problem is with the motor...